# Android Studio Emulator (Flutter) - Virtual keyboard pops up every time you type including screens where there is no text-field

Tags: android-studio, flutter, android-emulator, virtual-keyboard

Normally on a smartphone this won't be an issue. However when using an emulator on a computer or mobiles with a physical keyboard, this becomes an annoying issue. I just would like to disable keyboard on screens where there is no text-field or anything to type such that typing doesn't open up the virtual keyboard for no reason. Looking for a way to just straight out disable virtual keyboard and enable it later when needed.

Comment: if it's just for emulator, you can disable on screen keyboard by going into phone settings>system>languages&input>physical Keyboard> disable show virtual keyboard. Sorry if I misunderstood your question if this is what you do not want.

Comment: @Xuzan i could do that but wouldn't that completely disable the virtual keyboard? I want it to be there when i want to type in a text-field however not when there is no need for it. Like on a screen where there is no text-field or anything to enter, but accidentally typing on my physical keyboard opens up the virtual keyboard anyways. I don't want this to happen.